# How to return cabinets not including hidden ones with DQL

Tags: dql, documentum

I'm trying to return all the cabinets on a repository in documentum but I don't want to include cabinets not viewable from the DA, something like

```
   select object_name from dm_cabinet where (hiddenAttribute = "false")
```

or

```
   select object_name from dm_cabinet where permissions > 4
```

in the documentation

```
  select object_name from dm_cabinet
```

is suppoed to return a list of all cabinets (including private) im trying to only return non private cabinets

Answer (score 3):

```
select object_name from dm_cabinet where is_private = 0
```

In general there is no built in hidden property within Documentum types. However, dm_cabinet is an exception from this rule. It has property is_private which is used to determine whether you can see or access this cabinet with client applications. Only owners are able to see their cabinets -> [link](http://documentumknowledge.blogspot.com/2010/04/manage-user-cabinets-visibility-to.html).

Speaking of objects in general you won't see it if you have permission **NONE(1)**, i.e. if you by name or group membership aren't listed with higher privilege than none.

Documentum has built in "group" *dm_world* which is used for representing users that aren't declaratively mentioned in permission set for specific object. By default this group has **READ (3)** permission for generic permission sets.

Comment: when I execute select object_name from dm_cabinet it returns more cabinets than are veiwable in the DA.. it says in the documentation that this query returns list of all cabinets (including private) what I want to do is return non private cabinets

Comment: are you sure that you execute query with the same users as the one you are logged in with DA?

Comment: yeah, I only know one login.. I'm doing the query by a call QueryResult queryResult = querySvc.Execute(query, queryEx, operationOptions); where query.Querystring = the query command

Answer (score 0):

I guess the query I was looking for was

```
  "select * from dm_cabinet where (a_is_hidden = 0 and is_private = 0) or (any r_folder_path in (select default_folder from dm_user where user_name = '" +
                    username + "'))";
```

this query mimic's the DA and returns only the cabinets that a user see's when logged into the DA